# Can I assign roles to Data Extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I want to design several role profiles in an account where I have 3 data extensions.
Those profiles should be able to watch only one of those data extensions and its contacts associated. Is it possible? How could I segment it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define access to **individual** Data Extensions by role or user.

Permissions on individual Data Extensions can be defined if they are moved to the Shared Data Extensions folder (assuming you have multiple Business Units), but these permissions apply to all users in the business unit (who have appropriate permissions).

The only method I can think of is to:

1. Create new Business Units in your account
2. Assign the respective users to each Business Unit
3. Move the Data Extensions to the Shared Data Extensions folder
4. Assign permissions to each Shared Data Extension by Business Unit from the 'Permissions' tab on the Shared Data Extension.